# Mathematical expression result assigned to a Bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, console-application

How do I save the result of evaluating a mathematical expression to a variable using bash? My code is the following:

```
W1=$(bpimagelist -U -d 11/01/2013 00:00:00 -e 11/05/2013 00:00:00 -pt FlashBackup-Windows | tail -n +3 | awk '{s+=$5} END {print s/1024/1024/1024}')    
W2=$(bpimagelist -U -d 11/01/2013 00:00:00 -e 11/05/2013 00:00:00 -pt MS-Windows | tail -n +3 | awk '{s+=$5} END {print s/1024/1024/1024}')

echo "$W1+$W2" | bc | awk '{printf "%.02f\n", $1}'
```

> > Console Output: `96.86`

I am looking for a code similar to this:

```
W="$W1+$W2" | bc | awk '{printf "%.02f\n", $1}'  (not correct syntax though)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
 W3=$( echo $W1+$W2 | bc )
```

... have you tried this?

Comment: [root@slcnpde089 admincmd]# W3=$( echo $W1+$W2 | bc )
[root@slcnpde089 admincmd]# echo &W3
[1] 14457

-bash: W3: command not found
[1]+  Done                    echo

Comment: Do not paste it directly to the console, type it adding " to the sum like this: W3=$( echo "$W1+$W2" | bc )  ,in my laptopt, it works both ways. I am using Debian with bash. (small tip, never use root account, use normal account with sudo)

Answer (score 1):

This would work if both `W1` and `W2` were integers:

```
(( W = W1 + W2 ))
```

It seems you may be dealing with floating point numbers, though, so something like this might work in that case:

```
W="$(bc <<< "${W1} + ${W2}")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Use back tics:

   W1=`command`
2. Use parens

   W1=$(command)

Your command can be as complex as what you have above (e.g. multiple commands joined with pipes)

Option 2 allows for nesting of commands, e.g.

```
W1=$(command1 $(command2))
```

Comment: You need to escape the back ticks in your example ("W1=\\`command\\`").