# bash script: argument took as command and it's not recognized

Tags: bash, shell

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
# set -o xtrace

input="${1:-}"
table="${2:-}"

length=$(jq length $input)
step=25

for i in {0..${length}..${step}}
  do 
    low_index=$i * ${step}
    high_index=$low_index + ${step} - 1

    echo $low_index
    echo $high_index

    jq \
      --arg table "$table" \
      --arg low_index $low_index \
      --arg high_index $high_index \
      '{$table: [.[$low_index:$high_index] | {"PutRequest": {"Item": map_values({S: .})}}]}' \
      csvjson.json > dynamo_${table}_${low_index}-${high_index}.json
done
```

This is the context of my directory:

```
$ ls
csvjson.json  splitter.sh
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting:

```
$ bash ./splitter.sh csvjson.json socs
./splitter.sh: line 19: csvjson.json: command not found
```

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code; please run it through http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: You probably have a space following the backslash on line 18, which means line 19 is  a new command, not a continuation of the previous command. I'm not sure how you get that far, though, with the failure to use `$(( ... ))` to set the values of `low_index` and `high_index`; you should be getting similar command-not-found errors from those lines.

Comment: `set -e` and `set -o errexit` do the same thing, and the user of either is controversial, at best. I recommend not using either one.

Comment: ...for more on that, see [the exercises in BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Comment: I'll slightly disagree with chepner.  There's no controversy.  Don't use `set -e`

Comment: BTW, running `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO' bash -x yourscript` would let you know which line it's failing on, which might have helped you find the problem yourself. (I'll also second the recommendation to use http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here).

Comment: Also, in general, calling jq over and over in a loop means you should be designing your code differently to do that looping *inside jq*. It's a powerful language, and includes looping constructs; no reason not to use them. (Granted, this can mean you need to loop over its output to sort it into different files, but if the output is organized appropriately -- f/e, destination name before the content -- that's not hard to do, and generally a fair bit more efficient, particularly if using a tool like awk for that second stage).

Comment: I'll disagree with the chorus. `set -e` is flawed, but still quite useful. Use it if you want to. I do. Either way -- it's an unhelpful sidetrack given the many real problems in the script.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, ...*you* can get away with `set -e` because you know its intricacies/gotchas/pitfalls. That's a long learning curve; it's one thing to know them yourself (and, hopefully, have your team's code reviewers also intimately familiar) and make cautious use, it's another thing to encourage someone who *doesn't* know the trouble they're getting into thereby to use the facility blindly. (chepner and I, probably amongst others, were long-time freenode #bash denizens, and have a lot of time spent helping non-experts; guiding people away from sources of problems reduces support load).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the line:

```
low_index=$i * ${step}
```

and assume that `i=0` (which given the code in the question, it will not be, but that is clearly the intent) and step=5. When the shell parses that line, on the first round of word expansions it expands to:

```
low_index=0 * 5
```

There's no field splitting necessary, so round 2 is a no-op.  The 3rd roundof expansion is pathname expansion, in which the `*` is expanded to all the names in the current directory, so the line expands to:

```
low_index=0 cvsjson.json splitter.sh 5
```

The shell tries to execute that line by looking for a file named `cvsjson.json` in PATH.

Comment: Would you agree with closing this as a duplicate to [Mathematical expression result assigned to a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138516/mathematical-expression-result-assigned-to-a-bash-variable), if a failure to do so correctly is the primary/only problem?

Comment: Maybe also with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash as a second duplicate, to cover the fault in `for i in {0..$length..$step}`.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a duplicate!